# Spring: @NestedConfigurationProperty List in @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring, properties, configuration, spring-boot

Hi I am trying to get the following configuration up and running.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
public class Config {

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private List<ServerConfiguration> servers = new ArrayList<ServerConfiguration>();

    public List<ServerConfiguration> getServers() {
        return this.servers;
    }
}

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server")
public class ServerConfiguration {
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

So, I want to have multiple server configs nested in objects.
I tried setting the properties with the following properties file. I can see that the list is added up by items but the members of the server are never set (name, description)

```
my.servers[0].name=test
my.servers[0].server.name=test
my.servers[1].name=test
my.servers[1].server.name=test
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You need to add setters and getters to `ServerConfiguration`
- You don't need to annotate class with nested properties with `@ConfigurationProperties`
- There is a mismatch in names between `ServerConfiguration.description` and property `my.servers[X].server.name=test`

Answer (score 8):

To extend what Maciej said already.

`@ConfigurationProperties` should be set only on *root* objects (that is objects that are responsible to handle a given prefix. There is no need to annotated nested objects with it.

`@NestedConfigurationProperty` is **only** used by the meta-data generator (to indicate that a property is not a single value but something we should explore to generate additional meta-data. In the case of the `List` there isn't any finite amount of properties so the meta-data will have to stop at the list.

In any case you need a getter and a setter for each singular property. We don't do field binding and we require a public getter to avoid exposing unnecessary properties in the meta-data.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the need of getters, it took me a while to find why my nested properties wasn't populated. Turned out it was due to missing getters.